# I'm trying to put a column before other and the application said is wrong

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating columns in mySql, practicing, but when I traid to use this formula:

```
alter table usuario
add Nombres varchar(50) not null
  before DNI;
```

Which gave the error:

> is not valid at this position expecting EOF, ';'

But if a change only the before, by after, there's not any problem.

```
alter table usuario
add Nombres varchar(50) not null
  after DNI;
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html), the only valid positional syntax for adding a column are:

- `after <column-name>`
- `first`

`before` is not supported.